# the day before last; the day before

Tags: vocabulary

> "Wish McGonagall favored us," said Harry. Professor McGonagall was
>   head of Gryffindor House, but it hadn't stopped her from giving them a
>   huge pile of homework **the day before**.
>
> –– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

*[The day before last](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/the+day,+week,+month,+etc.+before+last#last_1__50)* is two days ago. Is *the day before* the same expression with the said, or is it yesterday?

Comment: This simply means *yesterday*, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The day before* is the way we backshift *yesterday* into the past tense. The same template is used for other temporal expressions which ordinarily take Speech Time as their Reference Time: *last night*, *tomorrow*, *last week*, *next week* and so forth, using *the T before* (*T* representing a unit of time such as *day* or *week*) or *a T earlier* for expressions designating an earlier time or date and *the T after* or *a T later* for expressions designating a later time.

In your passage for instance, *the day before* means the day before the day Harry expressed this wish. At the time, Harry would have said "She gave us a huge pile of homework yesterday".

If this passage had occurred two days after the homework was assigned, Harry would have said "She gave us a huge pile of homework day before yesterday" and JKR would have report it as "It hadn't stopped her from giving them a huge pile of homework two days before", or "two days earlier".

Comment: Is there no need of an article: a huge pile of homework [the] day before yesterday?

Comment: @Listenever Not ordinarily. There's only one each of yesterday, day before yesterday, tomorrow, etc, so in effect it's a name.

Comment: I think the article thing might be regional. I'd understand it without the article, but I do expect it (my brain automatically added it in when I was reading your answer; I didn't notice until I looked back after reading the comments!). I can see the *the* being elided if you're speaking quickly or casually, but (at least where I'm from) the *the* is usually included. +1 regardless; great answer! (cc @Listenever)